# Meteor / Jasmine Object is not defined

Tags: meteor, coffeescript, jasmine

I am trying to find out how to write a **server-unit-test** with jasmine.

This is what I have so far:

/both/posts.coffee

```
@Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');

class @Post extends Minimongoid
  @_collection: @Posts

  @defaults:
    title: ''

  validate: ->
    unless @title.length > 5
      @error('title', 'Title is required and should be longer than 5 letters.')
```

/tests/server/unit/posts/spec/postSpec.coffee

```
describe 'Post', ->
  post = undefined
  beforeEach ->
    post = new Post()

  describe 'fields', ->
    it 'should be able to assign title with strings', ->
      title = "The Title"
      post.title = title

      expect(post.title).toBe title
```

server console:

```
(STDERR) [sanjo:jasmine]: The code has syntax errors. [ReferenceError: Minimongoid is not defined]
```

What is wrong there? How can I get this simple test passed?

Comment: I think there is a problem with the stub/mock for 'Post' generated from jasmine. Try to write your own stub for this colection.

Comment: that's wired. What I wanna do is a test, which confirms that the collections have certain fields and validations, by using Collection2 (schema) and Minimongoid. So you mean I have to create an additional file which "mocks" the Collection "Post" in the tests folder for testing this?

Comment: read from here https://github.com/Sanjo/meteor-jasmine under Server Unit Test Mode <The Meteor API and all packages are stubbed in this mode>. What you want to do is more like an integration test.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working when I moved the whole content of the UNIT-Test to the INTEGRATION-Test folder and prepended the code with

/tests/server/integration/posts/spec/postSpec.coffee

```
Jasmine.onTest ->
 # my code
```

Now is all green. Thank you @Marius Darila